# Rules on specific fields on Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would like to check that my data do not contain a certain field.

```
 allow write,update: if (request.resource.data.brand.userID ==  request.auth.uid) &&
           !(plan in request.resource.data.brand.userData) && !(brand in request.resource.data.brand);
```

The last two statements gives error that `plan` and `brand` are unknown.

My doc is like this :

```
{

brand: {
  brand:xxxx
  ..
   userData:{
       paid:{}
   }

}
```

I would like to make sure that no one can write to the field `brand.brand`, and `brand.userData.paid`. Rest of fields inside can be written to.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to disable a field is :

```
allow create: if !("ranking" in request.resource.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few errors:

1. You write you want to prevent write to `paid` but your rule shows `plan`
2. You should use string instead a variable name, so `"brand"` instead of `brand` for instance (hence the error you get)
3. You want the fields `brand.brand`, and `brand.userData.paid` to be read-only, right? But your rule would prevent them from even being in the document as request.resource.data is the full final document, not only what you are just writing.

Summing it all, this rule should do it:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.brand.userID ==  request.auth.uid
  && request.resource.data.brand.userData.paid == resource.data.brand.userData.paid
  && request.resource.data.brand.brand == resource.data.brand.brand;
```

But if you indeed want to to deny any writes to these fields, use

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.brand.userID ==  request.auth.uid
  && !('paid' in request.resource.data.brand.userData)
  && !('brand' in request.resource.data.brand);
```